# Can a non citizen who lives abroad but has paid SS tax for 40 quarters get the benefit?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, social-security

I paid SS tax for 40 quarters when I was a permanent resident of US. Now I live abroad. Will I be eligible for getting social security benefits?

Most likely the answer is no but why not ask? :-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, actually. With string attached. There's [a short FAQ](https://www.ssa.gov/international/61-011.pdf) on the SSA website that addresses this question. They emphasize citizens from other American countries, but they also discuss cases which are general.

Keep in mind that if you're covered by a totalization agreement, the results will be different.